# How to convert Object[] filled with tokens to an Integer Array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, arraylist

I am trying to write a method that takes in an Object[] that is populated with tokens and converts it to an array of integers.

I started out with an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> colArr = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then populated it with tokens from a .txt file:

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    colArr.add(st.nextToken());
}
```

then converted it to an Object[]:

```
Object[] newColArr = colArr.toArray();
```

I now need to write a method that converts this Object[] to an Integer so that I can add certain elements together.  This is what I tried:

```
public static Integer[] convert(Object[] objectArray){
    Integer[] intArray = new Integer[objectArray.length];

    for(int i=0; i<objectArray.length; i++){
        intArray[i] = (Integer) objectArray[i];
    }
    return intArray;
}
```

but got "*Error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `Integer.valueOf(objectArray[i])` instead of casting like `(Integer)objectArray[i]`

EDIT:

To clarify, remember that Integer.valueOf() is simply a boxed object around Integer.parseInt().. so you have to handle NumberFormatException.
If you are quite sure that your text file will only contain integers, you could simply have an arraylist of integers and do the Integer.valueOf(tokenizer.nextToken())

Comment: @Mike -- change your container array to Double and do `Double.valueOf(objectArray[i])`. If you want `double` instead of `Double`, do `Double.parseDouble(objectArray[i])` .. API reference is your friend.http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Answer (score 2):

Integer.parseInt( string ); works for getting an Integer from String

Answer (score 2):

loop through your array of strings and use Integer.parseInt();

Answer (score 2):

You can't typecast directly from a java.lang.String to a java.lang.Integer, they are two totally different objects. Instead try doing:

```
Integer.parseInt(objectArray[i])
```

Don't forget to handle java.lang.NumberFormatException. And one more thing, you don't need to do the intermediary conversion to Object array. Unless of course your using that for something else you didn't mention. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

if you know, that the object array contains strings, you can use Integer.parseInt() to convert  the String to a Integer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [Lists.transform](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29).

```
List<String> numberList=Lists.newArrayList("1","2","3");
    List<Integer> trnsList = Lists.transform(numberList,new Function<String,Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String arg0) {
        return Integer.valueOf(arg0);
     }
    });
    Integer[] intArr=trnsList.toArray(new Integer[trnsList.size()]);
```